# Vue actualizing variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm using vue.js and I have an app with

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
       return {
          elements: json_data,
       }
    }
})
```

I also have a js file that I import in my html:

```
<script src="javascriptFile.js" defer></script>
```

The `json_data` is a global variable inside the `javascriptFile.js`. When I modify the file, my vue app doesn't reload the component I'm using with the new data. How can I do that?

Comment: Hummm perhaps because the object is a *live* entity and retains it's dynamic state in-memory. Have you tried to (if I got the question right) to store an original copy of your JSON data using a combination of `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 0):

From Vue docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

> ## data
>
> The data object for the Vue instance. Vue will recursively convert its
> properties into getter/setters to make it “reactive”.

As you are manipulating the data value outside of Vue (without using `this.json_data`), you are not allowing Vue to track the changes and react to it. You should either move the external logic into the component (as methods) so that you set the value of json_data with `this.json_data` or use Vuex if your application is complex enough.